# How to make Task Serializable in HBase using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I was trying to write data in HBase using Spark but getting the exception `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`. I was trying to open connection on each worker node using the following code snippet:

```
 val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
 val tableName = args(1)
 conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)
 val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)
 val tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName)
 val columnDesc = new HColumnDescriptor("cf".getBytes()).setBloomFilterType(BloomType.ROWCOL).setMaxVersions(5)
 tableDesc.addFamily(columnDesc)
 admin.createTable(tableDesc)

 rddData.foreachPartition( part => {
    val table = new HTable(conf, tableName)
    part.foreach( elem => {
      var put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(elem._1))
      put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("col"), Bytes.toBytes(elem._2))
      table.put(put)
   })
   table.flushCommits()
 })
```

How can I make task serializable while writing on HBase using spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken conf (instance of hadoop Configuration) is not serializable.

Write your code in such a way that all the non-serializable parts are in the foreachPartition block (so that it is executed on the nodes). Here is an example where I create a second conf etc..:

`

```
rddData.foreachPartition( part => {
     val conf2 = HBaseConfiguration.create()
     val tableName2 = args(1)
     conf2.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName2)
     val table2 = new HTable(conf2, tableName2)
     part.foreach( elem => {
      var put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(elem._1))
      put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("col"), Bytes.toBytes(elem._2))
      table2.put(put)
   })
   table2.flushCommits()
 })
```

`